# django admin fieldsets - adding fields of related models

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-models

I have a model `Employee` with a OneToOne relationship with `User`. I'm trying to include in the Employee admin some User fields (`first_name, last_name, username, email`), in order to edit those fields directly from the Employee Add/Change form, but I still haven't figured out how to do it.

I see another time do this kind of thing in a similar way, but now I have a fieldset error:

`Unknown field(s) (first_name) specified for Employee. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class EmployeeAdmin`

here's the code:

```
# FIELDSETS
default_employee_fieldset = (
    ('General', {
        'fields': (
                ('user', 'full_name',),
            ),
        }),
    # ..OTHER FIELDS NOT INCLUDED
    )

finance_fields_employee_fieldset = [
    ('General', {
        'fields': (
                ('full_name',),
                ('first_name', 'last_name')
        ),
        }),
    # ..OTHER FIELDS NOT INCLUDED
    ]



# ADMIN FORM
class EmployeeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'] = forms.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
        self.fields['last_name'] = forms.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)

        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            user = kwargs['instance'].user
            self.fields['first_name'].initial = user.first_name
            self.fields['last_name'].initial = user.last_name



# MODEL ADMIN
class EmployeeAdmin(ExtendedAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'department', 'line_manager', 'acting_line_manager', 'jobtitle', 'office', 'payroll_id',)
    search_fields = ('user__username', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name',
                     'line_manager__user__first_name', 'line_manager__user__last_name')
    list_filter = ('department', 'grade', 'clearance', 'office', 'user__is_active', 'user__is_staff',
                   'ready_for_paid_work')
    fieldsets = default_employee_fieldset

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = {'title': 'Employee details'}
        return super(EmployeeAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if object_id:
            try:
                record = Employee.objects.get(id=object_id)
                extra_context = {'title': 'Edit employee record: %s' % (str(record),)}
            except (ValueError, Employee.DoesNotExist):
                pass
        # Generate a new CSRF token as this page contains sensitive data
        rotate_token(request)
        return super(EmployeeAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EmployeeAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        elif request.user.has_perm('myapp.change_all_employees'):
            if request.user.has_perm('myapp.change_ex_employees'):
                return qs.filter(user__is_staff=True)
            else:
                return qs.filter(user__is_staff=True, user__is_active=True)
        else:
            return qs.filter(user__is_staff=True, user__is_active=True).filter(
                Q(line_manager=request.user.employee) |
                Q(acting_line_manager=request.user.employee) |
                Q(user=request.user)
            )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form = EmployeeAdminForm
        if obj:
            if request.user.has_perm('myapp.change_hr_employee_data'):
                self.readonly_fields = ('user', )
                self.exclude = None
                self.fieldsets = finance_fields_employee_fieldset
            elif request.user.has_perm('myapp.change_employee_data_operations'):
                if request.user == obj.user:
                    # set readonly fields
                    self.exclude = None
                    self.fieldsets = finance_fields_employee_fieldset
                else:
                     # set readonly fields
                    self.exclude = ('employer_pension_contribution', 'employee_pension_contribution',)
                    self.fieldsets = default_employee_fieldset
            else:
                # if user is in AAA department and not employee's linemanager and not own record
                if request.user.employee.department == settings.DPTS['AAA']
                    if request.user == obj.user:
                        # set readonly fields
                    else:
                        # set readonly fields
                        self.exclude = ('account_number', 'sort_code', 'salary',
                                        'employer_pension_contribution', 'employee_pension_contribution',)
                        self.fieldsets = default_employee_fieldset
                else:
                    # if user is editing his own record
                    if request.user == obj.user:
                        # set readonly fields
                        self.exclude = ('account_reference', 'payroll_id',)
                        self.fieldsets = finance_fields_employee_fieldset[0:-2]
                    # if user is editing some for whom is line manager
                    else:
                        if request.user.employee == obj.line_manager or \
                                        request.user.employee == obj.acting_line_manager:
                            # set readonly fields
                            self.fieldsets = default_employee_fieldset
                            self.exclude = ('employer_pension_contribution', 'employee_pension_contribution',)
        else:
            self.readonly_fields = ()
            self.exclude = ()
            self.fieldsets = default_employee_fieldset
        form = super(EmployeeAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form.request = request        
        return form



    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:
            old_obj = Employee.objects.get(id=obj.id)
            if obj.jobtitle != old_obj.jobtitle:
                employee_detail_change_notification(obj, 'job title', obj.jobtitle.name)
            if obj.line_manager != old_obj.line_manager:
                employee_detail_change_notification(obj, 'line manager', obj.line_manager)
            if obj.acting_line_manager != old_obj.acting_line_manager:
                employee_detail_change_notification(obj, 'acting line manager', obj.acting_line_manager)
            if obj.home_address_line1 != old_obj.home_address_line1 or \
               obj.home_address_line2 != old_obj.home_address_line2 or\
               obj.home_address_line3 != old_obj.home_address_line3 or\
               obj.home_address_city != old_obj.home_address_city or\
               obj.home_address_postcode != old_obj.home_address_postcode or\
               obj.home_address_country != old_obj.home_address_country or\
               obj.home_address_phone != old_obj.home_address_phone or\
               obj.personal_email != old_obj.personal_email:
                new_address = '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\nPhone: %s\nEmail: %s' %(
                    obj.home_address_line1,
                    obj.home_address_line2,
                    obj.home_address_line3,
                    obj.home_address_city,
                    obj.home_address_postcode,
                    obj.get_home_address_country_display(),
                    obj.home_address_phone,
                    obj.personal_email,
                )
                employee_detail_change_notification(obj, 'home address details', new_address)
            if obj.marital_status != old_obj.marital_status:
                employee_detail_change_notification(obj, 'marital_status', obj.get_marital_status_display())
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason Admin doesn't find user_name is that the user_name field isn't defined on your custom form at class level. It is only defined in `__init__`.  When the admin inspects the form for available fields it has access only to the class, not an initialized form. So inspecting the form class doesn't show that user_name is available.

Define all the fields directly on class level instead of the form's `__init__` method. If you don't need all the fields for all cases, then delete fields as needed from the form's fields dictionary in the `__init__` method as needed.

You could maybe also do this in the reverse direction - adding Employee information to User edit page? This can be done as documented in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#adding-userprofile-fields-to-the-admin.

Finally, it seems you are reaching the stage where it might be easier to implement the features you want without using Admin - while Django's Admin does have a lot of extensibility features, at some point writing your own implementation will be easier than using Admin.

Comment: I already tried the inline way, but it doesn't seems to work in "opposite" direction. I'll try with your suggestion, defining user fields outside init, I'll let you know. Stay tuned please :) tnx

Comment: +1 for "reached the stage where django admin is not enough" anyway