# django admin, displaying of dates

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been playing around with my test project and encountered a problem

(Please ignore my naming as I am merely testing and a beginner)

I have this model:

```
class APPLICANT_DATA(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Applicant'
        verbose_name_plural = u'The Data Of Applicants'

    FIRST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    LAST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    MIDDLE_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    BIRTH_DAY = models.DateTimeField()

    ADDRESS = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    REGION = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CITY = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ZIP = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    EMAIL = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    PHONE_NUM = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def DATE_OF_BIRTH(self):
        return self.BIRTH_DAY.strftime("%b %d %Y")
```

admin.py:

```
class Applicant_List(APPLICANT_DATA):

    class  Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = u'Applicant'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Applicants'

class applicant(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Applicant_List
    list_display = ('FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'EMAIL', 'DATE_OF_BIRTH', 'APPLICATION_DATE', 'APP_STATUS', 'SCHEDULED_AT', 'HAS_RECORD', 'JOB_CATEGORY', 'EMPLOYEE_ASSIGNED')

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            if not request.user.is_superuser:
                uname =  request.user.get_full_name()
                if str(obj.EMPLOYEE_ASSIGNED) != str(uname):

                    self.readonly_fields = [field.name for field in obj.__class__._meta.fields]
                    return self.readonly_fields
                else:
                    self.readonly_fields = ['FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'EMAIL', 'JOB_CATEGORY', 'ADDRESS', 'REGION', 'CITY', 'ZIP', 'EMAIL', 'PHONE_NUM', 'DATE_OF_BIRTH']
                return self.readonly_fields
            else:
                self.readonly_fields = ['FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'EMAIL', 'JOB_CATEGORY', 'ADDRESS', 'REGION', 'CITY', 'ZIP', 'EMAIL', 'PHONE_NUM', 'DATE_OF_BIRTH']
            return self.readonly_fields
```

I am using `proxy` to my models as I need the model to be registered again for another purpose

Work fine in the admin until I used `get_readonly_fields`.

I am using `get_readonly_fields` to make the field read only if the admin user is not a super user

The error says:

```
Unknown field(s) (DATE_OF_BIRTH) specified for Applicant_List. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class applicant.
```

Here's my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/@dmin/transactions/applicant_list/22/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'frontend',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sessions.models',
 'file_maintenance',
 'reports',
 'transactions',
 'admin_reorder',
 'admin_notifications',
 'django_twilio')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.models.User',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder')


Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
 233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lolwat\Desktop\ITSWEBSITE\transactions\admin.py" in change_view
  211.         return super(applicant, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=extra_context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1519.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1456.         ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in get_form
  703.                              % (e, self.__class__.__name__))

Exception Type: FieldError at /@dmin/transactions/applicant_list/22/
Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (DATE_OF_BIRTH) specified for Applicant_List. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class applicant.
```

Or are there other ways of changing the display in admin?

django 1.8

New traceback from removing grappelli and any other form of adding context to my admin interface(change_view, changelist_view .. etc.)

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/@dmin/transactions/applicant_list/22/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'frontend',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sessions.models',
 'file_maintenance',
 'reports',
 'transactions',
 'admin_reorder',
 'admin_notifications',
 'django_twilio')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.models.User',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1519.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1456.         ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in get_form
  703.                              % (e, self.__class__.__name__))

Exception Type: FieldError at /@dmin/transactions/applicant_list/22/
Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (DATE_OF_BIRTH) specified for Applicant_List. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class applicant.
```

Comment: @Alasdair, it is possible to include models methods: "A read-only field can not only display data from a model’s field, it can also display the output of a model’s method or a method of the ModelAdmin class itself." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: @AntoinePinsard my mistake.

Comment: Your code is bad indented, is it a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Is there another way to change the date display in the admin? Removing `DATE_OF_BIRTH` or the `get_readonly_fields` removes the error.

Comment: What you are doing should work. Unless the method definition is bad indented.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard Yes, I do not have indention errors (corrected my post)

Comment: Please post the entire model admin.

Comment: I would guess SomeModel is not Application_List. And DATE_OF_BIRTH is not defined in Application_List. By the way, way all these caps?

Comment: As an aside, it's not a good idea to set `self.readonly_fields`. It would be better to do `readonly_fields = [...]`, then `return readonly_fields`.

Comment: Noted, thanks, anyway, I have updated my post

Comment: Your Application_List models should be on your models.py, otherwise it wont be discovered.

Comment: The case style you use is really unusual.

Comment: The examples that I have seen while searching for `proxy` is that they are in the admin(works in my project regardless though or maybe I understood it wrong), anyway, if either the `DATE_OF_BIRTH` or `get_readonly_fields` is removed the error disappears, so other than what I have done, is there another possible way to change the format of date in the admin(custom forms maybe?)

Comment: Can you post the function with this line? 
`C:\Users\lolwat\Desktop\ITSWEBSITE\transactions\admin.py in change_view line 211`
If you have an invalid field name in `readonly_fields` a different error should be raised. It would be a AttributeError. Which version of django are you using? It's possible that one of the third party plugins in your admin is causing this? You could try to disable grappelli etc. to find out if the bug is related to one of those.

Comment: I suspect this question and answer is relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735252/django-admin-fieldsets-adding-fields-of-related-models

You should consider writing custom views and user interface for your app instead of using the django admin. It works great when you use within the limits it's designed for. But you will find yourself facing a lot of bugs like when you try to hack the django admin into doing something that is not supported in the documented api.

Comment: I removed `change_view` or anything that adds context to the admin interface from my code, removed grappelli, still the same error. Posted the second traceback

Comment: I don't know. You could try to see what happens if you take away the `get_readonly_fields` method and use for instance `fields = readonly_fields = ['FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'DATE_OF_BIRTH']` instead?

Comment: Yes, that works, I think the error comes from `get_readonly_fields`

Comment: I guess you have to debug this, using divide and conquer. Add the method back bit by bit, and see when the bug reappears. I would start by removing all assignments to `self.readonly_fields` inside the method. This is a hidden side effect, and a very common cause of hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Your `get_readonly_fields` is missing an `else` branch for when `obj` is `None`. I would also change the method so that it doesn't change `self.readonly_fields`, as I recommended before.